# writing to an USB optical mouse

Tags: usb, input-devices

On the internet I find a lot of examples of people reading from the `/dev/input/mouseX` device the `dX`, `dY` and `status` byte from an USB optical mouse.

From some research I found out that such an USB optical mouse can be reset, the streaming frequency can be set etc. all by sending some control codes to the mouse.

To which Linux device (`/dev/...`) should I write these control codes after which I can listen to the `/dev/input/mouseX` for the answer?

I could not find any concrete info on the internet. What I saw was that there exist a so-called `hidraw` device but no explanation about how to us it. From the desktop it is possible to change the settings of the parameters of the optical mouse, so there must be a possibility to write to it.

A lot of verification about `udev`, `udevadm` and `lsusb` in order to detect device and bus parameters of the mouse and the input device to which it is connected, but no clear info about the output channel.

I would appreciate VERY much to get in contact with who can help me!

Regards

Comment: Just by chance I got one small step closer via this link http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/devices.html